# How to prevent page refresh on anchor href

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using the code below.

```
<a ng-href="" ng-click="do()" eat-click>Click Me</a>
module.directive('eatClick', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        $(element).click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    }
})
```

Is there a better way to do this? Please share. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I was facing with href='javascipt:void(0)' issue, Then I found above code and I think this is best answer. please tell me if you have good approach other than this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: use href='#' or href='javascript:void(0)' that is best

Comment: This does not works in angular js

Comment: If you aren't going to use the href then is there even a need to be using anchor tags? You can attach ng-click to any HTML elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`event.preventDefault()`, works properly in this case. You can also use ng-href tag of angular for alternative solution.

```
$(element).click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

You can also try below:-

```
$('a[href=""]').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of defining directive, only ng-href="" is enough. Just replace all href with ng-href.